# Python lzjb decoder?

Tags: python, compression

I would like to use jslzjb  https://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/ to compress my js data. However, I also need to be able to decompress it in Python. I looked at  pylzjb https://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/, as jslzjb suggests,  but it only works with Python 2.6. I have Python2.7.

Any other libraries out there? I need the client side encoding to be fast, which is why I am trying jslzjb.

Comment: *but it only works with Python 2.6*. What makes you think it won't work with Python 2.7 then?

Comment: Ah, it only provides you with .so or .pyd files. That is rather dumb.

Comment: Have you tried checking out the source and running `setup.py` yourself? Are you on Windows or another platform?

Comment: Boy, this project does its darndest to not be useable to anyone. The `setup.py` file uses a private module `Iuppiter` not included in the reporistory.

Comment: Yup, just discovered that, too.

Comment: Last but not least, the project mixes C and C++, the latter only to provide a Boost-based Python extension wrapper.

Comment: It appears that on Linux, you are supposed to cd into `Linux32_Release` and use `make`, but you have to have the Boost headers installed when you do. The author only used Boost to create the Python wrapper for the `compress.c` file, a rather round-about way of handling the library. It feels almost like it would be easier to use `ctypes` to access a library version of `compress.c` instead.

Comment: If you do try to use the makefile, make sure you change `-lpython2.6` in `objects.mk` to `-lpython2.7`.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I can use it if it doesn't work on Windows, too, though.

Comment: If you are on Windows, then you'll need Visual Studio and boost, load the project file, alter the python2.6 link to python2.7 and compile.

Comment: @user984003 I'd love it if you had a look at my [python-lzjb](https://github.com/unwind/python-lzjb) package. I do realize this question is a bit old, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not to toot my own horn too much, but you might want to check out my [python-lzjb](https://github.com/unwind/python-lzjb) project, which is simply a port of the LZJB compression and decompression code to pure 100% Python. So it's very easy to get going, nothing to compile.

This question sure is old, but it might be a place to start.